# selenium: checkbox not getting enabled?

Tags: selenium

I have a webpage where I have a text field/box and two checkboxes. 
The checkboxes are enabled only after something is typed inside the textbox.

When i do this manually everything is fine. But when i try it with selenium, the checkbox does not get enabled, even after writing some text in the textbox.

Could someone please help me with this problem?

Apache License, Version 2.0

I am trying on firefox

code to type test: I am using python:

```
class FieldElement(Text):
    def __init__(self):
        self.locator = "css=input#fieldname"

class main_class(mainpage):
username = FieldElement()

self.username = "respective_text"
```

Comment: selenium 1 or 2?? also any specific browser??

Comment: also we need to see the code that you use to type text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I had to guess you are probably using the wrong API to set the test and that is why your javascript event is not being fired.. Dont use method like SetText or its equivalent..

use the method `TypeKeys` or something similar.

take a look at this: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.DefaultSelenium.TypeKeys.html

Comment: ok now the checkbox is enabled but somehow the 'EDIT', 'TOOLS' and one more dropdowns get clicked on the browser. THis is wht it did:

Comment: must be some other thign that you are doing probably with mouse events... anyways could u mark this answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where send_keys was not working correctly, but I found a work-around by using javascript to fix the html by-hand.

Something like:

`self.driver.execute("document.getElementById('myElement').checked = true;")`